# Добавление ListView в Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml

Есть несколько вкладок Fragment при использовании BottomNavigationView.

> 

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.intents.IntentsFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_visualtable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/countriesList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

При добавлении ListView в xml фрагмента и начальной инициализации в onCreate, приложение закрывается с ошибкой "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference"

> 

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<State> states = new ArrayList();
    ListView countriesList;
    StateAdapter stateAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_intents, R.id.navigation_addintent, R.id.navigation_notes, R.id.navigation_settings)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);


        // начальная инициализация списка
        setInitialData();
        // получаем элемент ListView
        countriesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.countriesList);
        // создаем адаптер
        stateAdapter = new StateAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, states);
        // устанавливаем адаптер
        countriesList.setAdapter(stateAdapter);
        // слушатель выбора в списке
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                // получаем выбранный пункт
                State selectedState = (State) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Был выбран пункт " + selectedState.getName(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        countriesList.setOnItemClickListener(itemListener);
    }

    private void setInitialData() {
        states.add(new State("Бразилия", "Бразилиа", R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp));
        states.add(new State("Аргентина", "Буэнос-Айрес", R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp));
        states.add(new State("Колумбия", "Богота", R.drawable.ic_dashboard_black_24dp));
        states.add(new State("Уругвай", "Монтевидео", R.drawable.ic_notifications_black_24dp));
        states.add(new State("Чили", "Сантьяго", R.drawable.ic_notifications_black_24dp));
    }

  /*  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.opacity_in, R.anim.opacity_out);
    }*/

}
```

Если добавлять ListView в activity_main.xml, а не в fragment_intents.xml приложение запускается и работает, но естественно ListView отображается при любой выбранной вкладке Fragment.
Как добавить ListView в Fragment, чтобы данной ошибки не возникало?

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.intents.IntentsFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_visualtable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/countriesList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```js
package com.example.projectintent.ui.intents;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.example.projectintent.R;

public class IntentsFragment extends Fragment {

    private IntentsViewModel intentsViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        intentsViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(IntentsViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_intents, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_visualtable);
        intentsViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: покажите пожалуйста фрагмент в который вы пытаетесь добавить данный виджет

Comment: Добавил фрагмент